# Sequences and Series Comparison

Tags: sequences-and-series

During a lecture, my lecturer said that the following is possible

$a_n < b_n$

but

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty {b_n} $

However, I am not able to come up or find any examples.

Help?

What's wrong with the following line of thought?

$a_n < b_n$

$\sum_{n=0}^N a_n < \sum_{n=0}^N {b_n} $

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{N=0}^N a_n < \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{N=0}^N {b_n} $

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n < \sum_{n=0}^\infty {b_n} $

Comment: `but` Why "*but*"? The statement is true, even though the second inequality can be improved to a strict one.

Comment: I agree. But I was told that improving the inequality to a strict one could be wrong. If so, are there any counter examples? I am not able to come up with any.

Comment: If $c_n \gt 0$ *and* $\sum_{n \ge 0} c_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n\ge 0} c_n \ge c_0  \gt 0$. Now consider $c_n=b_n-a_n$. Else, if you are not given that both series are convergent, then the second inequality doesn't make sense to begin with.

Comment: In particular, your current "proof" is not correct, as taking limits does not preserve strict inequalities in general. You need a slightly different argument (as the one outlined by @dxiv) to establish it.

Comment: Am I right to say that if the series is convergent, taking limits preserve strict inequalities?

Comment: And if it's not, it does not make sense in comparing them?

Comment: @David In this case it does, but *proving* it cannot be done the way you did.

Comment: @ClementC. I agree that my 'proof' is wrong.

Comment: I'm still not very familiar with taking limits, but would you know if the condition $c_n > 0$ is removed, what could be done to prove the statement?

Comment: @David `if the series is convergent, taking limits preserve strict inequalities?` Yes. `if it's not, it does not make sense in comparing them?` In *my* books, yes. But you'd better doublecheck what *your* book says about infinities and divergency. Though uncommon, yet I've seen conventions used where for example $\sum n = \infty = \sum (n+1)$, or even $\sum (-1)^n = ? \lt \infty = \sum 1^n$.

Comment: @David P.S. Just to clarify this part `if the series is convergent, taking limits preserve strict inequalities?`. If you meant that $a_n \lt b_n \implies \sum a_n \lt \sum b_n$ then the answer is yes, as written in my previous comment. But if you meant the other "*taking limits*" under the edited-in `What's wrong with the following line of thought?` then the answer is no, as pointed out by @ClementC.

Comment: alright! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is impossible unless the series are divergent to plus or minus $\infty$.

New: added some justification.
Denote $A_n := \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ and $B_n := \sum_{k=0}^n b_k$.
Note that
$$B_n - A_n = \sum_{k=0}^n (b_k-a_k) > \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (b_k-a_k) > \cdots > b_0-a_0 > 0.$$
Thus the gap between the partial sums *increases* and is always greater than  $b_0-a_0>0$.
Now if $A_n\to A$ and $B_n\to B$, where $A,B$ are real numbers, then for sure $B-A\geq b_0-a_0>0$.
However, $A_n\to\infty$ and $B_n\to \infty$ is also possible if, e.g., $a_n\equiv 1$ and $b_n\equiv 2$.

Answer (score 1):

For two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$, if $a_n < b_n \forall n \in N$, then necessarily $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \lt \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$, assuming both series converge.

As a motivation for the proof, consider this: there are two glasses $A$ and $B$. You poured $2$ units of water into $A$ and $3$ units into $B$. Initially, $B$ has $1$ unit more water. Then you keep adding water to both glasses, but always add a bit more to $B$ than to $A$. You can then be assured that there will always be at least $1$ unit difference in water levels. If the glasses never overflow (both series converge), their final levels also differ by at least $1$ unit.

The proof, as it turns out, is quite trivial. Consider 
$$c_n = b_n - a_n$$
Clearly, $c_n \gt 0 ~\forall n$. Then, 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_n > c_1$$ meaning the partial sum sequence has a limit that is at least $c_1$. Assuming that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = a_0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n = b_0$, $b_0 - a_0 > c_1$.

That said, I would like to mention three things.

1. Since $x > y \implies x \ge y$, the statement your lecturer made is not technically wrong. He/she could have made the stronger statement containing the strict inequality, but this is not wrong.
2. Taking limit on both sides may not preserve inequality. While it is true that $\frac{1}{n+1} \lt \frac{1}{n}~ \forall n\in N$, the limits of both sequences are $0$.
3. A limit might not even exist in the first place. For example, $-n < \frac{1}{2^n} ~ \forall n$ but the left limit doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 0):

Confusion:

Let $s_m \lt r_m$, $m\in \mathbb{N}, $

convergent sequences.

Then

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n \le \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}r_n.$

The limits could(!)  be equal.

Example:

$s_n = 1-1/n;$ $r_n = 1+1/n.$

Note: a sequence $s_n$ can be a partial sum.